# How to git stash some files in a script?

Tags: node.js, git, git-stash

I'm writing a Node script that create a git stash dynamically.
The purpose is to create a single stash entry with some files in it, while leaving all the other changes unchanged in the working tree.

All the files to be stashed are stored in a JS Array. Beware it can contains hundreds of files.

I can't call `git stash save -- <file1>` for each file as it will create N stash entries. `git stash save -- <file1> <file2> <file3> etc...` may be too long a for single command, given the number of files to handle.

How can I make a script executing multiple git commands to create step by step a single stash entry ?
... Or there is another solution I didn't expect ?

Thank you !

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Git doesn't traffic in files; it traffics in _commits_. A stash is a _commit_. Every commit represents _all_ your files. The notion of a stash containing "some files" is incoherent. A stash is a commit whose parents are the index and the working tree. If your goal is to record the current state of some files, make a commit to which you `git add` only those files, or just copy the files elsewhere.

Comment: @matt: technically a stash is a minimum of two commits, stored with the working-tree commit formed as a merge of the two or three commits that make up the stash. But yes, instead of making a stash, it's probably wiser to just make a regular commit here.

Comment: @torek Yes, I simplified for the sake of making the main point.

Comment: After some tests, the way « git stash -u -- file1 file2 etc » behaves is what I’m looking for. It creates a stash entry containing all the changes to specified files and reset them to the HEAD, while leave all other files in the working copy and their respective status untouched. The main problem is that do it in a single command can be risky because I’ve hundreds of files to stash, the corresponding command may be too long

Comment: I’ve also heard about « git stash create » and « git stash store ». But is there anyway to create a stash this way, add changes to the stash created step by step, then store it ? These two commands are undocumented and I didn’t find any example over the internet…